# What keyword can I replace final with to make my appbar variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created an appbar function to call whenever I need to create an app bar but the keyword final before it makes it difficult to add an onPressed functionality to an iconButton on the appBar. How can I go round this problem and have it change state when the iconButton is pressed?

```
 final appBar = AppBar(
      elevation: 2.0,
      title: Text(
              'HestiaLets App',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: null),,
    );
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe your *actual problem* instead of finding a best guess solution. What problem do you have adding an onPressed method? Why would that problem be connected to the word "final"?

Comment: why not make it a widget and pass a callback function to onpressed?